# How to retrieve files from Django FileSystemStorage uploaded in a multisteps form using formtools wizard

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 3.0 and python 3.8.2 to develop an ads website. To add a post, I used Django formtools wizard. It worked and everything goes nicely. I could save the multiform data. However, I could not retrieve the files from the FileSystemStorage so I can save them. Hence, any help to achieve this or suggestion is much appreciated. I want to retrieve uploaded files, save them to the data base and then delete them from the wizard (from the  FileSystemStorage).  Note: there is no error and everything is working except that the uploaded files are not saved to the data base even though they are available in the FileSystemStorage. Thus, I want to retrieve them to be able to save them to the data base.
Here is the view class:

```
TEMPLATES = {"CommonForm": "towns/salehslist/ads_main_form.html",
         "JobForm": "towns/salehslist/forms/jobPostForm.html",
         }


FORMS = [
        ("CommonForm", CommonForm),
        ("JobForm", JobForm, JobImagesForm), 
        ]

class PostWizard(SessionWizardView):

    # The form wizard itself; will not be called directly by urls.py,
    # but rather wrapped in a function that provide the condition_dictionary
    _condition_dict = {  # a dictionary with key=step, value=callable function that return True to show step and False to not
        "CommonForm": True,  # callable function that says to always show this step
        "JobForm": select_second_step,  # conditional callable for verifying whether to show step two
       
    }

    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(
        location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "photos")
)

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list, form_dict, **kwargs):

        # form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
        # print(form_data)

        data = {k: v for form in form_list for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items()}
        data["posted_by"] = self.request.user
        instance = Job.objects.create(**data)

        print("YOU ARE HERE")
        print(self.request.FILES.getlist("files"))

        for file in self.request.FILES.getlist("files"):
            print(file)
            img_instance = JobImages.objects.create(job=instance, images=file)

            img_instance.save()

        return HttpResponse("<h1>Post Page </h1>")
```

Here is the url:

```
url(r'^post/$', PostWizard.as_view(FORMS, condition_dict = PostWizard._condition_dict)),
```

Here is the html template:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    {% load static %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    {% load i18n %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{%  static 'towns/assets/fontawesome-free-5-12-0-we/js/all.js' %}">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'towns/assets/bootstrap-4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'towns/assets/fontawesome-free-5-12-0-we/scc/fontawesome.min.css' %}">
    

    <!-- file uploader font -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"  href="{% static 'towns/assets/fileuploader-2.2/dist/font/font-fileuploader.css' %}" >

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'towns/style/forms/jobPostForm.css' %}">





</head>
<body>



    <div class="container">
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col-lg-6 my-auto">

                    <div class="breadcrumb">
                            <div class="ads-form-title">
                                  Job Post 
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <form class="" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate id="jobPost">

                        {% csrf_token %} 
                        {{ wizard.management_form }}
                        {{ wizard.form.media }}
                      
                        <hr>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                
                        
                              <div>
                                  {{ wizard.management_form }}
                                    {% if wizard.form.forms %}
                                        {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
                                        {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
                                            {{ form|crispy }}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% else %}
                                        {{ wizard.form|crispy }}
                                    {% endif %}
                              </div>

                        
                            </div>
                        <hr>


                        <!-- upload images  -->
                        <!-- file input -->
                        <input type="file" name="files" class="files">

                        



                        
                        <center>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="position:relative; width: 33%; height: 100%;"> Submit  </button>
                        </center>
                    </form>


            </div>



        </div>
    </div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src=" {% static 'towns/assets/jquery-3.5.0.min.js' %}">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=" {% static 'towns/assets/bootstrap-4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'towns/assets/fileuploader-2.2/dist/jquery.fileuploader.min.js' %}" >
    </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you say: retrieve the files from the FileSystemStorage so I can save them. what do you mean, save to a Model?

Comment: Also, why you want to save them, because when you submit the whole form, all the data and files are saved to the model, right?

Comment: No, it is not right. Django formtools wizard keep the data in a session, and in the done method you have to retrieve the data and save it to the data base. I did that. images that I uploaded are uploaded to the FileSystemStorage. Thus, I want to retrieve and save them to the data base.

Comment: under your ```def done```, you already saved it to a model ```img_instance = JobImages.objects.create(job=instance, images=file)```, right? So, to retrive, isn't it just like any other files you saved to a model?

Comment: this code did not work. because  self.request.FILES.getlist("files") return empty list. So no file was saved. However, when I checked photos folder, I found all images there. Thus, the code "self.request.FILES.getlist("files")" is not the right way. Hence, I posted the question asking for the right way to do it.

Comment: 'files' is the correct name since it is the name used in front end form. However, both "files" and "images" return empty list. I am sure there is away to retrieve files from the file storage since I think ' request" in the last step of multistep form will not hold any file.

Comment: there is an image form that is submitted successfully and validated through Django form wizard. There is no error. The only thing I need the right way to retrieve the files from FileSystemStorage.

Comment: how many images are you uploading? are you tring to save these images to different model than Job?

Comment: there are two models: Job, and JobImages, images should be saved into JobImages and this so clear in this code: for file in self.request.FILES.getlist("files"):
            print(file)
            img_instance = JobImages.objects.create(job=instance, images=file)

            img_instance.save()

Comment: Yes I saw it. Just to be sure. Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 1):

When user hit `submit` button of the form wizard, `def post()` method is called. `def post()` will

1. validate the form and
2. save data and files into session.
3. then if the current page is the last page, it will
   `render_done`, which is `def done()`

The reason why your `request.files` is empty is because, the current `request` does not have files or data associated with it. All your data and files are saved to the session when you hit the `submit` buttons which are preceding the `done()` method.

Since I do not know how your form is structured, I am not sure how to definetely solve your problem. But something like below should do:

```
# iterate over all forms in the form_list
for form in form_list: 

    # check if current form has files
    if bool(self.get_form_step_files(form)):

         # if yes, do something
         uploadedfiles = form.files
         print(uploadedfiles)
         
         for key, value in uploadedfiles.items():
             jobimage = JobImage(job=?, image=value)
             jobimage.save()
```

**Update**
wihtout your model, form structure, and template, it is difficult to come out with complete solution. I am posting a minimum working example.

**1. in models.py**

```
class MyPost(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Photo(models.Model):
    mypost = models.ForeignKey(MyPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**2. In forms,** you will not include photoform, because you are trying to uplaod more than one images.

```
from .models import MyPost, Image
from django import forms

class step_first_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyPost
        fields = ['field1']

class step_second_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyPost
        fields = ['field2']
```

3. in template, you can keep your first template same as whatever you have. For the second one, say, you will have MyPost's `field2` and 2 image inputs, you will change it to:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}

 {{wizard.form.field2}}

    <input type="file"  name ="imagefile1"  >
    <input type="file"  name ="imagefile2"  >

{% endif %}
</table>
.......
.....
.....
</form>
```

- make sure you include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` otherwise your files will not be uploaded.
- make sure you have different names for filefield otherwise only one
  will be saved to your model.

**4. in views.py**

```
def done(self, form_list, form_dict, **kwargs):
        data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
        
        # you can print out and inspect this data, and you will know 
        # the below code.
        # you will need to modify data[0]['field1'] etc ...
        print(data)

        mypost = MyPost()
        mypost.field1 = data[0]['field1']
        
        mypost.field2=data[1]['field2']
        mypost.save()

        print('mypost')
        print(mypost)

        # the below part is for saving image files to model

        for form in form_list:
            
            # check which form has files
            if bool(self.get_form_step_files(form)):
                
                uploadedfiles= form.files

                print(form.files)  

                for key, value in uploadedfiles.items():
                    photo = Photo(mypost=mypost,photo=value)
                    photo.save()
            else:
                print('not bool')

        return render ##### whatever template you want to render
```

Comment: I updated my asnwer, use ```bool``` rather than ```isinstance```. Even with ```isinstance``` you should get non-empty uploadedfiles. in my hand, it prints ```{'imagefile': <UploadedFile: img7.jpg (image/jpeg)>}```. And if I check admin, the image is saved into model.

Comment: Thank you ha-neul for your response. In fact, when I looked into the template, I found only jobForm was rendered. The JobImagesForm was not. I am still uploading the images using Jquery plugin to upload images. Yet, they seemed are not submitted with the post request. I updated the question to include the form_list

Comment: could you show your template? where your file is uploaded, do you have fields like <input type="file" name="imagefile">

Comment: worked for me with two models. In first template, only fields from parent model. In second template, I did not have ImageForm, just had several  <input type="file" name="image1" > with different names with parent form's fields. Then just override ```def done``` using my above code plus retrieve data for parent model.

Comment: I update the question to include the html template

Comment: Hi, i did not have time wait for your template. I just updated with a minum  (but working) code for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for your appreciated answers. However, in your solution you split one model into 2 forms while in my project I emerged two forms in one step

Comment: This does not matter. Because all fields you entered regardless which model, you will retrieve them in def done method with cleaned data. To form wizard, they are all in one form-list. You will put each one of the data into whatever model they belong to.

Comment: I tried your code. There were no files uploaded to photos folder neither available in cleaned data. I added " enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: Because we did not put ```photo``` field in the ```forms.py```, you will not get any info about this ```photo``` in your cleaned_data. cleaned_data only includes the fields that you put into the```forms.py```. Where the files go? check your media/ folder, or whichever your photo field set for the ```uploaded_to=``` in your models.py.

Comment: I did do that. Any way, It seems very hacky and complicated to combined 2 different models into one form or combined 2 different forms into one step. I just neglect the idea to combined 2 forms into one step. I made them into 2 different steps and It did work. The last thing I would ask before accepting your answer, when I want to get uploaded files through "uploadedfiles= form.files"  it return only the last file even though there were 4 files uploaded in the same request or post and all files are available in photos. It seems they are over written each other.

Comment: glad it started working out. If you are uploading multiple files and if you are rending ```<input>``` manually, you need to make sure that their names are different. You should use ```file1```, ```file2```, ```file3``` etc. Otherwise, only one will be there.

Comment: I am using jquery plugin and all files are named differently.

Comment: hmm, I am getting ```{'imagefile1': <UploadedFile: img5.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 'imagefile2': <UploadedFile: img6.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 'imagefile3': <UploadedFile: img7.jpg (image/jpeg)>}
```.  in your case, what do you get? was the name point to the last input of jquery plugin input?

Comment: I added this code to JobImageForm: widgets = {

            'image': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True,}),
        }. It accept multiples images but only one image (last image) was saved.

Comment: If you want to upload multiple files using a form associated with Model, you have to use formset. Your JobImage model only has one image model field, so one Jobimage instance can only take one image

Comment: Because of this reason, I used fileinput that did not come from JobImage Form. Basically form without model. Now, if your jquery allow upload multiple files in one input field, use hard coded input like I suggested. Do not associate input field with your JobImage model.

Comment: If you always only have 4 images or less than 4 images, you can simply put 4 filefield in your model and render them as JobImage form. This way, you do not even need do uploaded files part, because all necessary info will be in the cleaned data.